# Is there Any way to show the toolbar columns menu by clicking on a customize Button outside the DataGrid in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, customization

Hi Inwas wondering if it's possible to trigger some DataGrid menus by clicking  a custom Button outside the component.
Thanks in advance

I don't know what else to write here, this thing is saying I have to. Is a little bit annoying but I really neeed to know if it's possible to do it.
I have been watched the official Docs but they doesn't seem to have información about this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.